# SQL between two dates statement using java string

Tags: java, sql, between, sql-date-functions

I'm trying to collect data from a table and then run a between two dates statement. The statement is created in a java string and then used by a resultSet variable using statement.executeQuery() with the string as the parameter.
This is how I create the string for the two dates:

```
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        int month = today.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int year = today.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int endOfMonth = today.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE);
        String sql;
        if (month < 10) {
            sql = "SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE DATE BETWEEN " + "#0" + month + "/01/" + year + "#" + " AND " + "#0" + month + "/" + endOfMonth + "/" + year + "#";
```

And when I print line this string the result is this:

```
SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE DATE BETWEEN #03/01/2015# AND #03/30/2015#
```

However, when i run this string through the executeQuery method this error occurs:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Lexical error at line 1, column 41.  Encountered: "#" (35), after : "".
```

Comment: why are you using `#` rather than `'`?

Comment: @legohead I was following a tutorial online which had hashes for some reason but this has solved the issue thanks for this

Comment: Which DBMS (Postgres, Oracle, ...) are you using? Date literals - even though defined by the SQL standard - are very different between the various DBMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL the dates need to be contained inside quotes `'` rather then hashtags `#`.

Once you change them this query should work.

```
SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE DATE BETWEEN '03/01/2015' AND '03/30/2015'
```

Rather than

```
SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE DATE BETWEEN #03/01/2015# AND #03/30/2015#
```

Comment: "*In SQL .. need to be contained inside quotes*" is not 100%. The SQL **standard** only defines a single way of specifying a date literal: `date '2015-01-03'` rather than a "plain" string. Whether or not a literal like `03/01/2015'` is accepted and treated as a date depends heavily on the actual DBMS being used.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  Calendar cal= Calendar.getInstance(); //Get the current date
  SimpleDateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MMM/dd"); //format it as per your requirement
  String today = formatter.format(cal.getTime());
  String lastday = formatter.format(cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE));

  String sql;
  sql = "SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE DATE BETWEEN " + CONVERT(Char(10), today,112) + " AND " + CONVERT(Char(10), lastday ,112)
```